# Avoid pushing more than one answer to a single question into an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

```
var answerArr = [];

$(".dropdown-item").on("click", function () {
    var value = $(this).val();
    answerArr.push(value);
    console.log(answerArr);
    for (var i = 0; i < answerArr.length; i++) {
        console.log(answerArr[i]);
    }

    $("#answerPlaceholder").text("Answer: " + value)
})
```

So I have 10 questions and the answers to each question are in a dropdown menu. Im pushing each answer value to an array but my problem is if someone changes their answer it will just add to the array instead of changing the answer. How do i make it so when an answer is changed it will delete the old value from the array and replace it with the new value?...not sure if the code will help. Thanks.

Comment: Can you add what your HTML looks like? Do you have ten different dropdown menus, and you're using the same click handler for each of them?

Comment: Yes, 10 different dropdown menus with the same class name.

Comment: Would it be easier if i generated each question through javascript instead?

Comment: Either that (so you can have a loop index variable) or attach a `data-` attribute to the DOM elements so you know which index to put the answers at.

Answer (score 0):

You need each dropdown to have a different `id` or `name` and then instead of pushing their values to an array, you would add them as a new entry on an object, using their `id` or `name` as key. You can then convert that object to array using `Object.values()` if you need to:

```js
const result = document.getElementById('result');

const answers = {};

document.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
  answers[e.target.name] = e.target.value;
  
  result.innerText = `
As an object:

${ JSON.stringify(answers, null, 2) }

As an array:

${ JSON.stringify(Object.values(answers), null, 2) }
  `;
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: monospace;
}

label {
  display: block;
}

select {
  display: block;
  margin: 8px 0 16px;
  padding: 8px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 25%;
}
```

```html
<label>
  Question 1
  
  <select name="q1">
    <option></option>
    <option>Answer 1A</option>
    <option>Answer 1B</option>
    <option>Answer 1C</option>
    <option>Answer 1D</option>
  </select>
</label>

<label>
  Question 2
  
  <select name="q2">
    <option></option>
    <option>Answer 2A</option>
    <option>Answer 2B</option>
    <option>Answer 2C</option>
    <option>Answer 2D</option>
  </select>
</label>

<label>
  Question 3
  
  <select name="q3">
    <option></option>
    <option>Answer 3A</option>
    <option>Answer 3B</option>
    <option>Answer 3C</option>
    <option>Answer 3D</option>
  </select>
</label>

<label>
  Question 4
  
  <select name="q4">
    <option></option>
    <option>Answer 4A</option>
    <option>Answer 4B</option>
    <option>Answer 4C</option>
    <option>Answer 4D</option>
  </select>
</label>

<pre id="result"></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than doing a `.push` into an Array, you'll want to consider *setting a value at a given index*. Before you can do that, you'll need to know which question a clicked on `.dropdown-item` is associated with. There are various ways to do that, for example:

1. When generating the answer dropdowns, attach a data attribute, like `data-question-index` to each. Then, you should be able to get the index like `const index = parseInt($(this).parent().data('question-index'), 10)`.
2. Keep an array of the answer dropdowns and do an `indexOf` check, like `const index = answerDropdowns.indexOf($(this).parent())`

Then, once you have an index, replace `answerArr.push(...)` with `answerArr[index] = ...`.

Answer (score 0):

@danziger and I did something pretty similar.

```
<div id="app">
      <div id="question1">
        <label for="question1DropDown">This is a question</label>
        <select id="question1DropDown" class="dropdown-item">
          <option value="answer1">Answer 1</option>
          <option value="answer2">Answer 2</option>
          <option value="answer3">Answer 3</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div id="question2">
        <label for="question2DropDown">This is the second question</label>
        <select id="question2DropDown" class="dropdown-item">
          <option value="answer1">Answer 1</option>
          <option value="answer2">Answer 2</option>
          <option value="answer3">Answer 3</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <pre id="answerPlaceholder"></pre>
    </div>
```

```
const answerMap = {};

$(".dropdown-item").on("change", function() {
  var value = $(this).val();
  var question = $(this)[0].id;
  answerMap[question] = value;

  $("#answerPlaceholder").text("Answer: " + JSON.stringify(answerMap, null, 2));
});
```

The code is largely what you already had except we're now adding a key to map the answer to. The user can go back and change answers and they only impact the answer for the key.

I changed the event from click to change. 
You should add some additional checking so that they cannot clear an answer by selecting a previously selected option.

I'm putting your answer results in a pre and stringify it so that the results are readable while you are debugging.

Here's my sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/simple-questionair-vcpbw?file=/script.js

Hope it helps!